# PowerShell String Timing

Tags: string, windows, powershell

I would like to take the following string and parse it in a way to output the length of each step. Time is listed as hr:min:sec.

**Edited Desired Output:**

[Step 2] took 2 minutes to complete.

[Test 3] took 3 minutes and 3 seconds to complete.

[Example 4] took 3 minutes to complete.

**edited to ask that each line item in brackets of $content is output individually rather than simply listing "Step"**

```
$Content =

[Step1]::14:37:11
[Step2]::14:39:11
[Test3]::14:42:14
[Example4]::14:45:14
```

Comment: What's content here? Raw text? An array?

Comment: is the time shown the _start_ or the _end_ of each step? your desired result indicates that the times are the END of each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would create an array of TimeSpan objects from the strings in `$content` and use these for the output.

**IF** `$content` is an array, use it straight away.
**IF** `$content` is a single string, you need to split it first with `$content = $content -split '\r?\n'`

```
# assuming $content is a single string, so we need to split into array:
$Content = @"

[Step1]::14:37:11
[Step2]::14:39:11
[Step3]::14:42:14
[Step4]::14:45:09
[Step5]::14:57:12
"@ -split '\r?\n'
```

Next loop through this string array and remove empty lines if there are any:

```
$times = $content | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
    $h, $m, $s = ($_.Trim() -replace '.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$', '$1') -split ':'
    [TimeSpan]::new([int]$h, [int]$m, [int]$s)
}

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $times.Count; $i++) {
    $timeDiff = $times[$i] - $times[$i - 1]
    # output the times taken for each step
    "Step $($i + 1) took $($timeDiff.ToString()) to complete."
}
```

Output:

```
Step 2 took 00:02:00 to complete.
Step 3 took 00:03:03 to complete.
Step 4 took 00:02:55 to complete.
Step 5 took 00:12:03 to complete.
```

Regex details for `-replace`:

```
.            Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *         Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(            Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}    Exactly 2 times
   :         Match the character “:” literally
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}    Exactly 2 times
   :         Match the character “:” literally
   \d        Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}    Exactly 2 times
)
$            Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

---

As per your new requirements in the comment, here's the somewhat altered code:

```
$Content = @"

[Step1]::14:37:11
[Step2]::14:39:11
[Test3]::14:42:14
[Example4]::14:45:14
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$times = $content | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } | ForEach-Object {
    # capture the action like '[Example4]' and the timestamp part
    $action, $processTime = $_.Trim() -split '::'
    # split the timestamp into Hours, Minutes, Seconds 
    $h, $m, $s = ($processTime -replace '.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})$', '$1') -split ':'
    # output an object with two properties, the action name and a TimeSpan
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'Action' = $action
        'Time'   = [TimeSpan]::new([int]$h, [int]$m, [int]$s)
    }
}

# loop through the returned array, get the time difference between steps
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $times.Count; $i++) {
    $timeDiff = $times[$i].Time - $times[$i - 1].Time
    # output the times taken for each step, in this new requirement rounded to show minutes only
    '{0} took {1} minutes to complete' -f $times[$i].Action, [math]::Round($timeDiff.TotalMinutes, 0)
}
```

Output:

```
[Step2] took 2 minutes to complete
[Test3] took 3 minutes to complete
[Example4] took 3 minutes to complete
```

Comment: Thank you, Theo!

Comment: Added an additional request to my initial question marked it bold... could you please take a look at this Theo?

Answer (score 0):

here's a slightly different way to get there ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates a set of time info lines to work with
  when ready to do this for real, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block and replace it with a call to `Get-Content`.
- filters out the lines that don't have a time info string
- iterates thru the lines starting @ 1 and ending @ the upper bound of the collection
  this skips `[step1]` since your desired output indicates the timing info is the END of each step.
- grabs the start time from the previous array item
- grabs the step name and end time from the current array item
- builds a string using the `-f` string format operator
- calcs the elapsed time by converting the time info to `timespan` objects & subtracting the start from the end
- sends that out to the screen

i was tempted to put the info into an array of PSCustomObjects, but you seem to want only the string output. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
$Content =

[Step1]::14:37:11
[Step2]::14:39:11
[Step3]::14:42:14
[Step4]::14:45:09
[Step5]::14:57:12
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file

# get rid of the no-time-info lines
$TimeLines = $InStuff -match '::'

foreach ($Index in 1..$TimeLines.GetUpperBound(0))
    {
    $StartTime = ($TimeLines[$Index - 1] -split '::')[-1]
    $Step, $EndTime = $TimeLines[$Index] -split '::'

    '{0} took {1} [hh:mm:ss] to complete.' -f $Step, ([timespan]$EndTime - [timespan]$StartTime)
    }
```

output ...

```
[Step2] took 00:02:00 [hh:mm:ss] to complete.
[Step3] took 00:03:03 [hh:mm:ss] to complete.
[Step4] took 00:02:55 [hh:mm:ss] to complete.
[Step5] took 00:12:03 [hh:mm:ss] to complete.
```

Comment: @Joseph - you are most welcome! [*grin*] the solution by `Theo` seems more robust ... i'm glad that you `Accepted` it ...

Comment: I have the content stored in a variable, $TestFile... with a file path of c:\windows\testfile.txt. How would your script need modified to address simply calling the variable instead of fake reading a text file?

Comment: as i mentioned in the notes, replace the entire "fake" block with a call to `Get-Content` to load the file into the `$InStuff` variable. plus, you can rename the $Var to whatever suits you. i use `$InStuff` as my default "no better name" variable name ... [*grin*]